# How can I tab between windows like in VS.NET?

Tags: atom-editor

It seems CTRL-TAB'ing through windows in Atom simple cycles through the open windows. In VS.NET when you CTRL-TAB you switch between your current and most recently active window (you TAB through your history, not through the list of open windows).

Is this possible to achieve in Atom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you are look [Tab Switcher](https://atom.io/packages/tab-switcher) package which according to description:

> Tab Switcher reorders your tabs according to least recent usage, making it easier to switch between active tabs.

Comment: Exactly right - only thing is Tab Switcher apparently crashes for me when attempting to use. I found tab-history though, that seems to perform the same action.

Comment: Great if Tab Switchers crashers for you , you might create an issue so repo owners knows.

Answer (score 0):

Tab Switcher doesn't use CTRL-TAB by default, but uses alt+[ for previous tab and alt+] for next tab. Another packages that uses the CTRL-TAB feature out of the box is [sensible-tab](https://atom.io/packages/sensible-tab).

There is an ongoing discussion about this topic in GitHub: https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/5344